# android unable to use hdmi in creative tab and need to be notified in all(maximum) devices as soon as hdmi is plugged

Tags: android, video, android-hardware, hdmi

may be possible duplicate of hdmi support in android.

I am working on XYZ video encrypted app.But need to manage hdmi also to overcome the encrypted video pitfall.

As per my search I found that these are not in official docs and are provided by specific vendors Api as that of **Motorola**.

I have explored much and found that these are vendor specific , there is no unique api or documentation to serve the needs of all the devices.

My device is:

**Creative ziio 7** OS :2.2.1 build number:v2.00.13-FROYO.

But please suggest and answer the following via the google white papers or your personal experience:

- If a certain android device has hdmi hardware support, then how can we detect it programmatically.
- If the hardware is supported in device. Then if the connection is    made to hdmi my app need to be notified about that.
  (like using a recevier etc).
- I am also unable to connect the hdmi in Creative ziio 7 with hdmi
  cable (AWM 1.3 cable)  to my hp notebook pro laptop

I have noticed about that certain vendors provide hdmi api like **MOTOROLA** http://developer.motorola.com/docs/motorola-hdmi-status-api/

Also we can detect the USB Plug Status in all devices by using

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ums_connected" />
```

So is there any way for **hdmi** also. But need to have a general concept to do the same for all devices.

Answer (score 2):

Although there does not appear to be an official standardized way of doing without using vendor specific APIs, on later versions of Android 3.0+, it seems like the Android source code references a broadcast action intent that most vendors seem to be implementing. This intent is "android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED". If you're targeting these later OS versions, this seems to be pretty reliable from my experience in detecting when HDMI is connected.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no HDMI support inherently in the platform. Each hardware vendor hacks up their own implementation via the hardware composer hardware abstraction layer. Meaning, there isn't a way for you to programmatically interact with anything HDMI related with the standard Android SDK.